# while loops for temperature falling over time

Tags: matlab, while-loop, temperature

I am new to MATLAB and am learning how to use while loops. I'm having trouble using the while loop to solve a problem where I need to calculate the temperature in a tank. The tank starts at 200 degrees and I need to find out how many days it takes until it drops below 45 and so far I can only get MATLAB to run through the program once and it stops at 168 degrees. If someone could help it would be much appreciated.

```
% This program will calculate the # of days it will take for the...
... temperature in the tank to drop below 45 degrees celsius
clc
clear
A = 60; %Surface area of the tank in m^2
t = 86400; %Number of seconds in a day 
Cp = 4980; %The heat capacity of the liquid in  J/(kg*°C)
Tair = 23; %Average temperature surrounding the tank in °C 
To = 200; %Average ethylene glycol temperature on day 0 in °C 
h = 9.2; %The heat transfer coefficient in W/(m2*°C)
m = 35000; %The mass of liquid in the tank in kg
n = 0; %The day
Tn=0
while (Tn < 45)
    Tn =((1-((h*A*t)/(m*Cp))^n)*To+Tair);
    n=n+1;
end
Tn
n
```

Comment: Without knowing how Matlab works, it seems that it initially enters the while loop because Tn is 0.  You perform the calculation the first time and it gives you a 23.  N is bumped up from 0 to 1, and the second time you get 0.726*200 + 23 which is 168.  N is bumped up again, but Tn is no longer under 45 and your while loop ends.  I'm guessing the calculation is wrong?

Comment: @Neil: You got half of the problem, it should be `while(Tn>45)`.

Comment: @Evan Streator: Grab pen and paper and solve your formula for n=0. You get `Tn=Tair` which is definitely wrong. This is what you would expect for `n=inf`

Comment: I know the correct answer is on the 6th day around 32 degrees. But I'm still struggling to get the loop to perform this.

Comment: So if I change Tn < 0 to Tn > 0 and run it again I still have no luck. I do not know what to set Tn equal to to continue the loop for longer. I had a missing parenthesis in the equation and fixed that and now can get the correct number when compared to a calculator however I'm still lost with Tn. It has to be defined before the while loop. @Neil

Comment: @EvanStreator: Please update the question and include the code you are using now.

Comment: Your problem would tend to suggest to write it Tn >= 45, but then Tn continues to grow, not diminish.  If it is supposed to eventually diminish, then that's fine, but otherwise the loop will never end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your formula is correct, this should do your job:

```
Tn=200;
while (Tn >= 45)
    Tn =((1-((h*A*t)/(m*Cp))^n)*To+Tair);
    n=n+1;
end
```

It will enter the while loop the first time for sure, and then calculate as long as the temperature is over 45 the new temperature for one additional day. But maybe there is also a problem with your formula?

Comment: The program worked now with this fix! Thank you very much!

Comment: Minor correction, Tn >= 45 (op mentioned dropping *below* 45).